# How would I get resharper to build me a simple fluent interface based on the current fields or props in a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

For example I have the following class:

```
public class PublishFacebookOpenGraphActionRequest
{
    public FacebookOpenGraphActions Action { get; private set; }
    public FacebookOpenGraphObjects ObjectType { get; private set; }
    public Uri Url { get; private set; }
    public Uri Image { get; private set; }
}
```

And I would like to be able to generate something like this from the current set of properties:

```
public class PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction
{
    public FacebookOpenGraphActions Action { get; private set; }
    public FacebookOpenGraphObjects ObjectType { get; private set; }
    public Uri Url { get; private set; }
    public Uri Image { get; private set; }

    public PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction WithAction(FacebookOpenGraphActions action)
    {
        this.Action = action;
        return this;
    }

    public PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction WithObjectType(FacebookOpenGraphObjects objectType)
    {
        this.ObjectType = objectType;
        return this;
    }

    public PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction WithUrl(Uri url)
    {
        this.Url = url;
        return this;
    }

    public PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction WithImage(Uri image)
    {
        this.Image = image;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have a conversion from all members of PublishFacebookOpenGraphActionRequest to a fluent interface.
But maybe an half-automated generation of a fluent property-WithMember-pair is also a small step forward. This is possible with a ***ReSharper Live Template***.

I have an example:

[image]

You can create the following code with that *Live Template*:

```
public FacebookOpenGraphActions Action { get; private set; }

public PublishFacebookOpenGraphAction WithAction(FacebookOpenGraphActions action)
{
    this.Action = action;
    return this;
}
```

by just typing `fluentProp` + *ENTER* and entering property name and its type.

Comment: Cool I will give you the answer until someone else comes up with a solition. Not sure if it is possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use *Visual Studio*'s ***Quick Replace*** (*Ctrl+H*) by using ***Regular expressions***.
See screenshot:

[image]

*Find what:* is set to: `:b*public:b+{:i}:b+{:i}:b+\{:b*get;:b*private:b*set;:b*\}:b*$`.
*Replace with:* is set to: `public \1 \2 { get; private set; }\n public _class_ With\2(\1 p\2)\n\{\nthis\.\2 = p\2;\nreturn this;\n\}\n`.

This adds a *With** member for all properties in current document. Unfortunatly I cannot find a way to set return type of *With** member. So I just set it to `_class_`. So you need to replace this `_class_` by class name (manually or by another *Quick Replace* run).